# Dataflow Python Streaming Autoscaling

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

When will Google Cloud Dataflow have support for Autoscaling on Python Streaming pipelines? This would help me lower costs, and have better reponse time for my pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

It is already available you can check the documentation below for more details - https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#autoscaling